# How do I get a cam lock out of a really deep hole?

Tags: woodworking, screws, self-assembly-furniture

I bought a 54" desk from a local Walmart, more specifically a BH&G cube organizer desk. While I was putting it together and following the instructions, I realized that the cam locks weren't joining with the screws no matter how far anti-clockwise I turned the screwdriver. This was strange since in a previous step, I managed to screw the cam locks and screws in place without any trouble. However, on further inspection, I realized that I had accidentally placed the problem cam locks further into their holes than I should have, where they normally only go in as far as the thread.

I tried to remove them with a screwdriver, but they don't seem to make any noticeable progress out of the hole. I tried lightly tapping the other end of the desk piece with a hammer, but that doesn't seem to work either. They seem to be really stuck in there. I'm just wondering how I would be able to fix this, any help is appreciated. Pictured below is a cam lock I managed to pop out with a screwdriver, a spare nail and luck, and a cam lock that's still burrowed in one of the holes.

[image: A cam lock in its hole]

[image: A cam lock]

Comment: Got pics? There are various types of cam-lock hardware. Seeing it might help us provide suggestions.

Comment: Try to tap with a hammer in the opposite direction.  For instance, if you are holding the piece with the cam-hole facing down and you want the cam lock piece to fall down, you have to tap the piece of wood upwards.

Comment: I edited my post and added pictures. And I tried the recommendation of tapping in the opposite direction and it didn't seem to budge.

Comment: That hole doesn’t go all the way through does it? I ask because it looks really deep compared to the thickness of the board. Also, the cam should spin freely, are you able to spin it without issue?

Comment: The hole ie deep, but it doesn't go all the way through. I believe it stops just before the other side. And the lock spins freely, it's just really snug inside the hole.

Answer (score 3):

Put some hot glue on the end of a dowel or other stick and put it in the hole.  Give it a minute to dry then gently rotate the stick (and cam) while pulling it out.  Hot glue would be a quick fix, but next step is a stronger glue that might take longer.

Final options - try to drill a hole into the center of the cam lock and threat a small screw into it and pull it out.  Or, if it's not in a very visible spot, drill a small hole in the opposite side and poke out the cam lock with a wire or pin.  Last method is fast, but will leave a visible hole on the "finished" side.